# I can not deploy the project into glassfish, when i used injections in entirymanager

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, glassfish

I can not deploy the project into glassfish, when i used injections in entirymanager. I use glassfish payara. 
My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="DT1">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/diplomPool</jta-data-source>
        <class>model.entity.ForeignSensor</class>
        <class>model.entity.Hous</class>
        <class>model.entity.Note</class>
        <class>model.entity.RommSensor</class>
        <class>model.entity.Room</class>
        <class>model.entity.TemperatureData</class>
        <class>model.entity.TemperatureStatistic</class>
        <class>model.entity.User</class>
        <class>model.entity.UsersInformation</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my servlet

```
@WebServlet("/TS")
public class TS extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public TS() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "DT1")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        String results = null;
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u.email FROM User u");
        List<String> names = q.getResultList();
        em.close();
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(names.toString());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

and when i deploy project into glassfish, i have [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ras4.png)

it is my log

> 2016-03-15T13:48:38.725+0200|Severe: Exception while deploying the app
>   [DT1] : Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [DT1] failed.
>   Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit. Internal Exception:
>   Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.2.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException Descriptor
>   Exceptions: 
>   --------------------------------------------------------- Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception
>   Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field
>   [temperature_statistics.ID].  Only one may be defined as writable, all
>   others must be specified read-only. Mapping:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[user] Descriptor:
>   RelationalDescriptor(model.entity.TemperatureStatistic -->
>   [DatabaseTable(temperature_statistics)]) Exception [EclipseLink-48]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception
>   Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field
>   [temperature_data.temperature_id].  Only one may be defined as
>   writable, all others must be specified read-only. Mapping:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[rommSensor]
>   Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(model.entity.TemperatureData -->
>   [DatabaseTable(temperature_data)]) Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.6.2.qualifier):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception
>   Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field
>   [users_information.ID].  Only one may be defined as writable, all
>   others must be specified read-only. Mapping:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[user] Descriptor:
>   RelationalDescriptor(model.entity.UsersInformation -->
>
> ### [DatabaseTable(users_information)]) Runtime Exceptions:
>
> Blockquote

Comment: So do you read your error messages? __Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [users_information.ID]__, __Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [temperature_data.temperature_id]__  why not post that class and explain why you have that error?